# Does anyone know the other reason for using future perfect here?

Tags: passive-voice, future-perfect

I wonder the reason why it has been here used FUTURE PERFECT!

> The building is hardly there to satisfy the needs of structure but, whatever its purpose or plan, structural needs will have had a vital hand in shaping its form.

Moreover, what does "structural needs will have had a vital hand in shaping its form" mean?

Source:
[*Understanding Buildings: A Multidisciplinary Approach*](http://books.google.com/books?id=baguAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=#v=onepage&q&f=true)

Comment: Does this statement assert that "the building is hardly there" or that it is not "there to satisfy the needs of the structure"? Could be interpreted both ways. Either way, FUTURE PERFECT indicates that this building is not yet built.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "will have had" means something that has not happened yet, but after the event looking back one would be able to say "has had".  This tense describes a past that will occur in the future, and is usually speculative or hypothetical in nature.

In this specific case, this statement "structural needs will have had a vital hand in shaping its form" means
"structural needs are vital in shaping its form", it's just put into a future tense because the building does not exist yet, but the author is supposing that when the building does exist, then these things would be true of the past.

I will simplify the tenses for you:

**original**

> The building is hardly there to satisfy the needs of structure but, whatever its purpose or plan, structural needs will have had a vital hand in shaping its form.

**revised**

> The building is there to satisfy only minimal needs of the structure, if at all.
>       However, the structural needs are vital in shaping the form of the building, which has yet to be built.

Another example, "Once I finish this pancake I will have had 5 pancakes."

It's a sort of future retrospective tense, where one is talking about a past tense that has not yet occurred, but is expected to occur. In the case you asked about, it introduces the information that the building does not yet exist, or that some other related event is still yet to take place in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much. FANTABULOUS. GREAT. AMAZING. YOUR EXPLANATIONS ARE GREAT. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: And, would you more the following?a past tense that has not yet occurred

Comment: These colours will have had an important for this wall.

 It means:

 the wall has not yet coloured, but it is expected to colour.


 Is my explanation right? if so, would you tell me when/where  do you prefer to use such a statement?

Comment: And, why the write has not said will have instead of will have had?

Comment: Or what is the difference between will have and will have had in this situation?

Comment: Let's simplify: "I will have a piece of cake" vs "I will have had a piece of cake". The first sentence refers to a specific point in the future where when you are going to consume, or are consuming, a piece of cake. While the second sentence refers to a specific point in the future AFTER you've already consumed the piece of cake, looking back on the time when you did. Does that clarify?

Comment: Another example: It is 9:55PM. You could say, "At 10PM you will have 10 minutes to shower." However, one could also say, "At 10:10PM you will have had 10 minutes to shower," because the ten minutes will have already happened at 10:10PM.